# How to use a templated alias or const variable to abbreviate a static const variable?

Tags: c++, templates, static, c++17, entity-component-system

I am writing an entity component system as an exercise with C++17. I'd like to have each component type, represented as a struct, to be associated with a unique identifier that may be used as a index into into a vector of bitsets in the component registry as an example. This works using the templated struct `ComponentType`. However, it feels verbose to write `ComponentType<Tag>::type` every time I'd like to get the value. I'd prefer to use something like `component_type_t<Tag>`. However, compilation fails using a templated alias and the implementation as below, though it compiles, using produces the following output. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
0
1
2
0
0
0
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
    
namespace ECS {
    struct ComponentTraits {
        using component_type = unsigned int;
    protected:
        static component_type types;
    };

    using component_type = ComponentTraits::component_type;
    component_type ComponentTraits::types = 0;

    template<typename Component> 
    struct ComponentType : public ComponentTraits {
        static const component_type type;
    };

    template<typename Component>
    const component_type ComponentType<Component>::type = types++;

    template<typename Component>
    const component_type component_type_t = ComponentType<Component>::type;

    //Components
    struct Tag {};
    struct Transform {};
    struct Mesh {};
    // and so on...
  
    ////Won't compile
    //template<typename Component>
    //using component_type_t = ComponentType<Component>::type;
};

int main() {
    using namespace ECS;

    std::cout << ComponentType<Tag>::type << std::endl;
    std::cout << ComponentType<Transform>::type << std::endl;
    std::cout << ComponentType<Mesh>::type << std::endl;

    std::cout << component_type_t<Tag> << std::endl;
    std::cout << component_type_t<Transform> << std::endl;
    std::cout << component_type_t<Mesh> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template<typename Component>`
`using component_type_t = decltype(ComponentType<Component>::type);`

Comment: First my friend your question is a little bit wage, second when I run your code I get different output of :```0
1
2
0
1
2 ```.

Comment: @newbie perhaps this is compiler specific then. However, I am using visual studio 2019 and it produces that output.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your templated `using` is not compiling because your `ComponentType` doesn't hold an alias, it holds variable storage.

```
using component_type = unsigned int;
static const component_type type; // this is not an alias

template<typename Component>
using component_type_t = ComponentType<Component>::type;
```

To fix that error you need to get its type by using `decltype`:

```
template<typename Component>
using component_type_t = decltype(ComponentType<Component>::type);
```

But this raises another problem, `component_type_t` never actually holds the value you expect, it actually holds the `component_type` which is `unsigned int` without any value assigned to it ( since it's an alias ), so when you call:

```
std::cout << component_type_t<Tag> << std::endl;
std::cout << component_type_t<Transform> << std::endl;
std::cout << component_type_t<Mesh> << std::endl;
```

It prints 0 because your compiler assigning 0 to uninitialized variables, you should not rely on this, because different compilers may deal with this differently.

So to fix this, you need to pass the value into a variable rather than pass its type:

```
template<typename T>
component_type component_type_t<T> = ComponentType<T>::type;
```

And your output will be:

```
0 // Tag 
1 // Transform
2 // Mesh
0 // Tag 
1 // Transform
2 // Mesh
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able build your suggestion. Rather I found after some fiddling, I obtained the desired output using a const reference for component_type_t.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Because I tested it on GCC/Clang and it was working fine.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: I have tested it on Visual Studio on my machine, and it produces your results...
Apparently, GCC/Clang knows how to redirect themself to the correct variable when not specifying where is the definition.

On your definition for `ComponentType<Component>::type` you missed to tell MSVC where is that `types++`, to fix this just change the entire line to: `const component_type ComponentType<Component>::type = ComponentType<Component>::types++;`

It should fix your issue.

Comment: Also since you using C++17 you might be want to look into applying `inline` on variables ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static ), it lets you save some duplicated code when dealing with `static`s.